# Correctly bind object instance property to a Label in code

Tags: wpf, vb.net, data-binding

This is supposed to be easy, yet I can't get it to work.

This is a simplified example so I can illustrate my problem. I have a `List(Of Object)` and I want to bind the `Content` of a `Label` to some property of an object in the list. I want to do this in code (Because those labels will be generated in runtime).

I create my object that will hold the value for the label and the list, that will hold those objects:

```
' The List to hold objects
Public Class BList
   Public Shared listy As New List(Of BindTest)
End Class

' Object to hold label text
Public Class BindTest
   Public Property Namy As String
End Class
```

Then I try to create the object and add it to the list. And try to set the binding for the label (for sake of simplicity, lets say I want bind to the first list item).

```
Dim bb As New BindTest
bb.Namy = "FirstName"
BList.listy.Add(bb)

B_label.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty, "Namy")
B_label.DataContext = BList.listy.Item(0)
```

So far it works fine and label shows "FirstName" as expected. But then if I try to change the value of that first item like this:

```
BList.listy.Item(0).Namy = "Something else"
```

nothing happens and the label is not updated.

Comment: Your property **Namy** does not implement **INotifyPropertyChanged**. See [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-2)

Comment: @MikeEason Thanks. That helped. I'm relatively new to WPF. I somehow thought, that that interface is automatically implemented by itself. I have to implement it manually, I see.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to [Mike Eason](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4363119/mike-eason).

I needed to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`. I somehow thought, that it would be implemented automatically with all that WPF default-way of databinding everything. Oh well, one needs implement this manually.

So for the code to work, this part:

```
' Object to hold label text
Public Class BindTest
   Public Property Namy As String
End Class
```

..must be changed to this:

```
' Object to hold label text
Public Class BindTest
    Implements INotifyPropertyChanged

Private _Namy As String
Public Property Namy 
    Set(value)
        _Namy = value
        _PropertyChanged("Namy")
    End Set
    Get
        Return _Namy 
    End Get
End Property

Private Sub _PropertyChanged(Optional ByVal PropertyName As String = Nothing)
    RaiseEvent PropertyChanged(Me, New PropertyChangedEventArgs(PropertyName))
End Sub
Private Event PropertyChanged(sender As Object, e As PropertyChangedEventArgs) Implements INotifyPropertyChanged.PropertyChanged
End Class
```